# How to use custom translations for requests in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Documentation [says](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation) to create directory with file by path: `resources/lang/xx/validation.php`.

Then add content of validation words:

```
return ['custom' => [
    'email' => [
        'required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
    ],
]];
```

How to use this for [Creating Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation) where is going validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just for deploying custom validation messages, e.g. whenever 'email' is 'required' it will return this message in place of the default message: `The email field is required.`

If you want to replace all the other messages take a look at `/resources/lang/en/validation.php` [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/lang/en/validation.php) and see all the basic messages which you can replace with your local language versions in your `/resources/lang/xx/validation.php`

If you want a custom message, find the `custom` array at line 130 and change to:

```
'custom' => [
    'price' => [
        'required' => 'The price is required! Please supply one.',
    ],
],
```

Then, be sure to set your app locale, e.g.

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
});
```

Or if your entire app is in another language, you could set `locale` in your `/config/app.php` on line 81.

Your usual validator will now use the messages in `/resources/lang/locale/validation.php`

Comment: Sorry, I have disinformated you, I meant how to use custom language translation for custom Requests too, can you extend answer with this information and I will accept you answer, please

Comment: what do you mean by a custom request?

Comment: I mean this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation  When you create own custom validation for incoming data, I need translate that

Comment: What is structure of this file? Is it array? And I send language as parameter via API, how to apply?

Comment: Seems I should to use global middleware to grap language and call `App::setLocale($locale);`

Comment: If your language is always the same, just set it in `/config/app.php`. Copy the file `/resources/lang/en/validation.php` and replace all the messages with your chosen language.